# How to use logistic regression with decay

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I have a dataset with binary outcomes. I use Logistic regression for making the prediction.

example of my data :

```
id    Col_A    ...    y
1       5      ...    1
2      10      ...    1
3     500      ...    0
4     705      ...    0
5       2      ...    1
```

I would like to apply a decay on my logistic regression function
i.e. the prediction result will depend on col_A: if col_A contains a high value the prediction must be converged to 0 (an exponential function). So that I will get probability value instead of binary

Is it possible to do that? and if it is possible how can I achieve it?

I use the followig Logistic regression source code:

```
class LogisticRegressionUsingGD:

    @staticmethod
    def sigmoid(x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


    @staticmethod
    def logit(theta, x):
        return np.dot(x, theta)

    def p_hat(self, theta, x):
        return self.sigmoid(self.logit(theta, x))

    def cost_function(self, theta, x, y):
        m = x.shape[0]
        a = y * np.log(self.p_hat(theta, x))
        b = (1 - y) * np.log(1 - self.p_hat(theta, x))
        total_cost = -(1 / m) * np.sum(a + b)
        return total_cost

    def gradient(self, theta, x, y):
        m = x.shape[0]
        return (1 / m) * np.dot(x.T, self.sigmoid(self.logit(theta, x)) - y)

    def fit(self, x, y, theta):
        opt_weights = fmin_tnc(func=self.cost_function, x0=theta, fprime=self.gradient, args=(x, y.flatten()))
        self.w_ = opt_weights[0]
        return self

    def predict(self, x):
        theta = self.w_[:, np.newaxis]
        return self.p_hat(theta, x)
```

Comment: "if col_A contains a high value the prediction must be converged to 0 (an exponential function)" - This may already happen, if the model ends up with a (large) negative coefficient on the `col_A` variable.

Comment: I use many others columns in logit fonction (and I couldnt reduce the number of them) so that the model doesn't behave according to the value of Col_A

Comment: I would like to apply something like decay or partial credit , if the logit of (Col_B, Col_C.... without making Col_A) get for exemple 0.95 as result of prediction and Col_A value = 200 I will reduce the value predicted to 0.81 for exemple ( based on an expontiel fonction (exp (-0.01*Col_A))